# How to convert tibble data with various classes from long to wide format problem using ONLY base R package?

Tags: r, data-science, reshape, tibble

I am trying to convert my dataset from long to wide format only using **base R packages and dplyr **only**** due to university's project requirements. I have tried to use reshape function, but I have encountered problems with converting them using the reshape() function.
My data looks like this *please note that in original dataset in geo column there are 27 countries and dates that go from 2000-02-01 to 2022-09-01*:

```
# A tibble: 8 × 3
  geo     time       values
  <chr>   <date>      <dbl>
1 Poland  2022-09-01   1.3 
2 Germany 2022-09-01   2.1 
3 Denmark 2022-09-01   3.2 
4 Greece  2022-09-01   4.1 
5 Poland  2022-08-01   1.1 
6 Germany 2022-08-01   2.7 
7 Denmark 2022-08-01   3.8 
8 Greece  2022-08-01   4.12
```

I want to convert that data into this format :

```
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  time       Poland Germany Denmark Greece
  <date>      <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2022-09-01    1       2       3     4   
2 2022-08-01    2.1     3.3     4.5   5.7 
3 2022-07-01    7       8       5     8   
4 2022-06-01   21.2     2.3     1.2   2.13
```

You can reproduce these two datasets with this code

Long data:

```
library(dplyr)

datasample <- matrix(c("Poland","Germany","Denmark","Greece","Poland","Germany","Denmark","Greece",'2022-09-01','2022-09-01','2022-09-01','2022-09-01','2022-08-01','2022-08-01','2022-08-01','2022-08-01',1.3,2.1,3.2,4.1,1.1,2.7,3.8,4.12),
                     ncol = 3,
                     byrow = FALSE)
colnames(datasample) <- c("geo","time","values")
data_tibble <- as_tibble(datasample)
data_tibble <- data_tibble %>% mutate(geo = as.character(geo),
                                      time = as.Date(time),
                                      values = as.double(values))
```

Wide data:

```
data_wide <- matrix(c("2022-09-01",1,2,3,4,"2022-08-01",2.1,3.3,4.5,5.7,"2022-07-01",7,8,5,8,"2022-06-01",21.2,2.3,1.2,2.13),ncol=5, byrow=TRUE)
colnames(data_wide) <- c("time", "Poland","Germany","Denmark","Greece")
data_wide <- as_tibble(data_wide)
data_wide <- data_wide %>%
  mutate(time = as.Date(time),
         Poland = as.double(Poland),
         Germany = as.double(Germany),
         Denmark = as.double(Denmark),
         Greece = as.double(Greece))
```

I tried to use the simple reshape function from base R library:

```
data_wide <- reshape(original_data, idvar = "time", timevar = "geo", direction = "wide")
```

and I get something like this:

```
# A tibble: 272 × 2
   time       values.c("Austria", "Belgium", "Bulgaria", "Cyprus", "Czech Republi…¹
   <date>                                                                     <dbl>
 1 2022-09-01                                                                    NA
 2 2022-08-01                                                                    NA
 3 2022-07-01                                                                    NA
 4 2022-06-01                                                                    NA
 5 2022-05-01                                                                    NA
 6 2022-04-01                                                                    NA
 7 2022-03-01                                                                    NA
 8 2022-02-01                                                                    NA
 9 2022-01-01                                                                    NA
10 2021-12-01                                                                    NA
```

This is something close to the result that I want but as you can see it is now divided into 2 columns
there should be time and seperate columns for each country but it is now a singular vector with country names.

How can i form that vector into seperate columns and insert the values to appropriate records?

Comment: Try `library(tidyr);pivot_wider(data_tibble, names_from = geo, values_from = values)` Or with `base R` `xtabs(values ~ time + geo, data_tibble)`

Comment: With your reshape code, it can be corrected as `reshape(transform(data_tibble, id = ave(seq_along(geo), geo, FUN = seq_along)) , idvar = c("id", "time"), direction = "wide", timevar = "geo")`